# Enable/disable a CheckBox column on edit/update

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have grid with a CheckBox column like this:

[image]

I want to simply enable the CheckBox of selected row "e" on Edit and disable after Update/Cancel. This is what I have tried:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkStatus")).Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

This is for enabling the CheckBox on Update/Edit:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    GridViewRow gvRow = GridView1.Rows[index];

    if (e.CommandName == "Edit" || e.CommandName == "Update")
    {
        ((CheckBox)gvRow.FindControl("chkStatus")).Enabled = true;
    }
    else if (e.CommandName == "Cancel")
    { 
    }
}
```

But the problem is that after each Edit/Update, RowDataBound fires and disables the CheckBox again.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Why does `RowDateBound` fire? Because you DataBind the grid again? Then either dont do that or load the datasource again which should now contain the updated value, so `Enabled=true`.

Comment: Yes .. I am firing databind() again .. thanks for the hint

Comment: Need more detail about where you are binding the grid, and you named CommandName as "Edit" and "Update" which needs RowEditing and RowUpdating events to be handled so are you bindig grid there?

Answer (score 1):

OK, found the solution.

Just needed to change to:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowState != DataControlRowState.Edit)
    {
        // Here logic to apply only on initial DataBinding...
    }
}
```